# Invalid Method...str_replace_once(Array)

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I am having some trouble with creating an A-Z index search in Magento. I already have created the code, however, I am getting an "invalid Method..." error:

> str_replace_once(Array (
>       [0] => &
>       [1] => ?
>       [2] => 127.0.0.1/mgn-default/electronics/cameras.html ) )

I don't know well PHP, here's the code used for:

```
<?php 
$search_array = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','ALL');

/*Find if the URL already contains any querystring variable or not */
if (strstr( $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), "&" ))
{
 $separator = '&'; 
}
else
{
    $separator = '?';
}
?>
    <div>
        <p class="view-mode-list-bot">
            <?php 
   $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('alpha');
   foreach ($search_array  as $search_array_value):

   /*Clean the URL*/
   if (strstr( $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), "?" ) )
   {
    $new_Url =  $this->str_replace_once('&','?',str_replace("?alpha=".trim($postData['alpha']),'',str_replace($separator."alpha=".trim($postData['alpha']),'',$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl())));
   }
   else
   {
    $new_Url = str_replace("?alpha=".trim($postData['alpha']),'',str_replace($separator."alpha=".trim($postData['alpha']),'',$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()));
   }

   $alphaURL = $new_Url.$separator.'alpha='.$search_array_value;
?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $alphaURL; ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?> <?php if($search_array_value == $postData){ echo 'remove_under'; } ?>"><?php echo $search_array_value; ?></a>   

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </p>
```

Any advise and help will be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Did you implement `str_replace_once()` yourself? Is it defined by Magento, and available in the surrounding object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know magneto but what I can see, is **no need** to test the url as you are. You should use the request instance.

i.e `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('alpha')`

It's confusing what you are actually trying to get with your loop as many of the varaiables referenced in the example could have any value. However, the below could help you see that the variables are accessible via the request object, such as:

```
$alpha = array('a','b','c', 'etc..');
/** fetch the request object **/
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$letter  = $request->getParam("letter"); // Would and return "k" from http://mysite.com?letter=k
/** Test if we found a letter in the url **/
if (null !== $letter) {
  /** output the alphabet as links with each letter value as a link parameter **/
  for ($x = 0; $x < 26; $x++) {
    echo '<p><a href="?letter=$alpha">$alpha[$x]</a></p>';
  } 
}
```

Lastly, it looks as if you are looking at the URL parameters as well as referencing `$_POST` data. In my experience, it's better to deal with just one request scope ($_GET/$_POST) at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. The Code itself is good I assume. The problem is, why do I get the error "invalid method...str_replace_once(Array ( [0] => & [1] => ? [2] => 127.0.0.1/mgn-default/electronics/cameras.html ) )